# AngularJS <textarea> how to set new string?

Tags: angularjs

i have the "textarea" tag where user input the message. If user press "Enter button", the comment sent to the server.

How i can make new string in comment (ctrl+enter) ? 
After the sending comment to the server, he appear in a current user (between 2 "p" tags) so, i also should parse new string in html.

```js
$scope.send = function(event, press){

  if(event.keyCode === 13 || press){
        addNewComment.addComment($scope.comment).then(function(obj){ });
    
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea class="comment" placeholder="Type a message here" ng-model="comment" ng-keydown="send($event)"></textarea>
```

Comment: You need to use Ajax http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp Get a little further with your attempts, and then post back what you have tried and what you cannot figure out.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to do when user hits enter?

Comment: i need to insert separating symbol of new string like /n/r. I need to insert mentioned symbol after pressing ctrl+enter

Comment: `$scope.comment += "\n\n";`